# Display proportion of data based on sum of a field

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have a problem with Tableau. In my worksheet I want to be able to use Sum(Field 1) to filter data I see on my sheet. So for example, If sum(sales)<20 only show the sales information which their sum is less than 20. When I try to create a calculated field to with the expression above Tableau converts it to a boolean filter instead of sliding my data to meet the filter criteria.

Is there any solution for the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could filter the result using an having clause

```
select my_key, sum(field1)
from my_table  
group by my_key
having sum(field1)<20
```

Comment: So the problem is using above rather than sliding data to display the part has sum(filed1) <20 it checks this as a boolean filter, means if the sum is less than 20 show all and otherwise nothing

Comment: your comment is not clear ..  you should update your question  .. and a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text

Comment: @reza Its behaving as it is expected to. I believe answer by scaisEdge should solve your problem. Alternatively, put the aggregated sum field in the filter pane and edit the filter to get the sliding option.